# What electrical work can I do legally in New Brunswick, Canada?

Tags: electrical

I've just moved in my first house a few weeks ago, a new construction, and there is a couple  outlets that I want to add and some that I want to move. I'm located in New Brunswick, Canada. There doesn't seem to be any electrical by-laws in my municipality/city, so I assume that I can follow the provincial laws. The provincial act can be found here: http://laws.gnb.ca/en/showpdf/cr/84-165.pdf

First question, there's a couple of data outlets that are not exactly where I need them, that I assume that I don't need any permit/license. They're Cat3/Cat5/Coax combo. I also want to add in an HDMI outlet at the back of the TV mount in the living room that goes down where my amp/HDMI switch is. Since these are all data outlets, I assume I don't need a permit or a license to do that work?

I also have two places where I'd like to add electrical outlets. For example, there's an electrical outlet behind the TV mount, but none down where I'd like my amp, can I just cut out a hole in the drywall, add a box, and fish a wire down from the existing outlet? Is this considered changing/modifying the circuits?

The the provincial act, near the bottom of the document, there's a section for "qualified persons". So it sounds like if you kinda know what you're doing, you can maintain your circuits. However, adding outlets sounds more like modifying the circuits.

According to the [wiring permit laws](http://www2.gnb.ca/content/gnb/en/services/services_renderer.1035.Electrical_Wiring_Permits.html), it seems like you only need a permit if you're going to change more than 10 outlets and/or you're dealing with more than 5kw of load.

I'm more worried about my insurances than anything else. I know what I'm doing, but if I do make a mistake, and there's an electrical fire, I don't want to void my insurance claim.

Can anyone enlight me?

Comment: You should contact your local government (building department), and ask them what you can do without a permit.

Comment: I figure that's the best way to go. Not many people from NB on StackExchange :) I'll post my answer once I received an answer from the local building department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer I got:

1)  First we have three types of installation as define by the definition in the Regulation 84-165.

> “type I installation” means the installation and repair of branch circuits, devices, motors and appliances on existing type II installations, including domestic ranges, water heaters and clothes dryers, but no alteration or addition, except for the installation of a domestic range, water heater or clothes dryer, shall exceed ten outlets or a total of five kilowatts;(installation de type I)
>
> “type II installation” means any electrical installation not exceeding two hundred amperes having a single phase supply of power less than three hundred volts between any two wires but possessing no features attributable to a type III installation;(installation de type II)
>
> “type III installation” means any electrical installation having one or more of the following features:(installation de type III)
>       (a) requiring a three phase supply of power;
>       (b) requiring a supply voltage exceeding three hundred volts between any two wires;
>       (c) having a service entrance installation exceeding two hundred amperes in current capacity

2) Then the regulation 84-165 10(1) says that you must be an electrical contractor with a group 3 or 2 licence to do any electrical work on these type of installation.

> 10(1)No person shall undertake to carry out
>       (a) a type III installation unless he is the holder of a valid Electrical Contractors Licence Group 3 issued or renewed under this Regulation, or
>       (b) a type II installation or a type I installation unless he is the holder of a valid Electrical Contractors Licence Group 3 issued or renewed under this Regulation or a valid Electrical Contractors Licence Group 2 renewed under this Regulation.

3) Also the regulation 84-165 11(1) says that you must have a valid N.B. electricians licence to work on an electrical installation.

> 11(1)No person shall make, repair or maintain an electrical installation unless he is authorized by
>       (a) a valid Electricians Licence Class 3 issued or renewed under this Regulation,
>       (b) a valid Electricians Licence Class 2 renewed under this Regulation, or
>       (c) a valid Industrial Electricians Licence issued or renewed under this Regulation.

4) So to summarize all this you must be a licence electrician working for an electrical contractor to performed any electrical installation or repair in the province of N.B. even replacing rec.,light switches, light fixtures etc.

As for the data/communication, it doesn't fall under DPS jurisdiction, so we can legally do anything data, phone or coax, which I wouldn't see why not.

Comment: In short, I can't do squat when it comes to electricity, even maintain my own property.

Comment: Wow, I'd be upset if that was the case in my house.  When you go to the "home improvement" stores in your area, can you even by light switches and outlets or are they only sold at "professional" stores?

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yep, I can buy everything. I can even buy circuit breakers and everything at Home Depot, or any other hardware store. Pretty dumb if you ask me :)

Answer (score 0):

The electrical inspector in my area (Southwest New Brunswick) informed me that a licensed electrician is even required to drill holes in studs, floor joists etc. and if a carpenter does it, it's illegal.